# AWS EventBridge rule triggers twice

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have CRON based rule in AWS EventBridge.
Event schedule is `cron(0 16 * * ? *)`. It triggers Lambda function at 16.00 UTC daily.

After I created this rule the first time, it triggered Lambda once - this is good.
But when I edited cron expression, it started firing 2 events at 16.00.
I removed this rule and created a new one but it also fires 2 events at 16.00.

Monitoring of Lambda function shows it's executed 2 times at around 16.00 every day:
[image]

This is CloudWatch for this rule:
[image]

**Summarizing everything I have a rule that should fire 1 event but it fires 2 events instead. Any ideas why there are 2 events?**
Looks like a bug in AWS EventBridge.

Comment: check your target there might be two lambda functions.

Comment: @Lamanus there is only one target, mentioned Lambda function.

Comment: AWS says in rare cases such duplicate events are possible, but my case is not rare https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eventbridge-troubleshooting.html#rule-triggered-more-than-once

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that my Lambda function runs longer than 15 seconds. However I have a maximum allowed duration set to 15 seconds and retries count (in case of errors in Lambda) is set to 2.

So the following happens:

1. AWS EventBridge triggers my Lambda once.
2. Lambda is executed within 16 seconds. All business logic is performed in it.
3. In the end Lambda is timed out (for being longer than 15 seconds) and returns error code.
4. Error triggers repeated invocation of the same Lambda.
5. Repeated invocation of Lambda takes less than 15 seconds to complete.
6. My business logic is performed twice.

**Solution is to increase timeout limit.**

FYI
I found it after finding errors in Lambda Monitoring dashboard, observing Lambda logs in CloudWatch and seeing "Task timed out after 15.01 seconds" message.